# Using css ::after to create horizontal dash after input without impacting other elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

using `::after` to create a "-" between two inputs. The issue is that I need to move the dash central between the two inputs, I have been trying to do this by adding `margin` or `padding` but then that pushes the second input further out which can't happen.

How can I adjust my current code to allow the "-" to move to the left/right without pushing other elements around?

```css
.column {
  padding-right: 24px;
  padding-left: 24px;
}

.styled-group, styled-group-two {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.styled-group::after {
  content: "-";
  margin: 0 5px;
  height: 1px;
}

.input-two {
  width: 45px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="styled-group">
      <input class="input-one" type="text">
    </div> 
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <div class="styled-group-two">
      <input class="input-two" type="text">
    </div> 
  </div>    
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/simoncunningham/pen/mdwMgyL

Comment: I'm not sure why you have different `margin` values but this causes the unequal spaces around the dash. Is [this](https://codepen.io/moshfeu/pen/xxrvLzW) what you want to have? Notice that you forgot `.` before `styled-group-two`

Comment: thanks Mosh - sorry, I made an edit to the snippet to reflect the issue more accurately - which includes two columns. hence the "-" clashing with their padding and moving the inputs further away.

Comment: Feels like your html structure is more complicated than needed. Is it given or you can change that however you like? If so, can you specify what can be changed? Anyway, I strongly recommend not to use `position: absolute` when there is other option - it's not always responsive, it breaks easily when things changed and it might look different in browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind giving margin to inputs, this can be handled by absolute positioning.

```css
.styled-group,
styled-group-two {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.styled-group input {
  margin: 0rem 1rem;
}

.styled-group::after {
  content: "-";
  position: absolute;
  left: 95%;
  height: 1px;
}

.input-two {
  width: 45px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```